# How many degrees of freedom are there when generating a joint probability function for $n$ different binary random variables?

Tags: probability

To generate a proper probability function one should assign a probability to all $2^n$ possible events.
One constraint is that the sum of the probabilities of all events must be equal to one - so this removes one degree of freedom.

I tried to think of any other constraints but couldn't find any.
Are there any other constraints? or is the answer $2^n - 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no other contraints.

Your formulation of the question is slightly unclear. You speak of $n$ events at first and then of $2^n$ events. I suspect that what you mean is: If $n$ events can occur independently of each other, then there are $2^n$ possible events, one for each subset of the $n$ events. Indeed there are $2^n-1$ degrees of freedom in the probability mass function in this case. More generally, if the sample space consists of $k$ elementary outcomes, there are $k-1$ degrees of freedom in the probability mass function.